# Accessing AutoCad Dynamic Block 'Block Properties Table' through C# Com Interoperability

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, autocad

I am using AutoCAD 2017 Professional with ObjectARX_2017_Win_64. I am attempting to query & modify the "Block Properties Table" property of a Dynamic block using COM Interoperability without success. The Table contains name headed Columns and multiple rows containing the data. The data is of type String and Integer.
Any help would be welcome in the "Do Stuff" section.

```
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    .
    .
    .
    public void DrawLayout(boards board, FormAutocad frmAutoCad)
    {
        double[] insertpoint = new double[] { 0, IP_CONNECTOR_Y, 0 };
        if (AcadLinkStart(frmAutoCad))
        {
            destdwg = acadApp.ActiveDocument;
            // Get all the standard blocks from BLOCK_REF and place in destination drawing
            CopyStandardBlocksToDrawing();
            AcadBlockReference o = destdwg.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertpoint, "041_CHASSIS", 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Ensure blocks are loaded in CopyStandardBlocksToDrawing

            Object[] attribs = o.GetAttributes() as object[];
            Object[] props = o.GetDynamicBlockProperties() as object[];
            foreach (var prop in props.OfType<AcadDynamicBlockReferenceProperty>())
            {
            if (prop.PropertyName == "My_Table")
            {
                 // Do Stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you only can get or set the property Value which corresponds to the row index in the table.

```
    Object[] props = o.GetDynamicBlockProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props.OfType<AcadDynamicBlockReferenceProperty>())
    {
        if (prop.PropertyName == "My_Table")
        {
            if (prop.Value != 0)
                prop.Value = (short)0; // <- reset to the first row
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks gileCAD. That's a shame. The Block Properties Table seemed like a perfect place to store custom tabulated data for the Block. Looks like I have to revert to parsing a multiline Attribute instead for 500+ parameters. I'll leave this thread open just in case somebody can pull a rabbit out of the hat.